# Equidecomposability of square and rectangle

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Two sets $A,B$ are equidecomposable if there exist finite partitions $A = A_1 \cup \dots A_n, B = B_1 \cup \dots \cup B_n$ such that $A_i$ and $B_i$ are congruent in regards to translations and rotations. I want to show that $R_1 = [0,2] \times [0,2]$ and $R_2 = [0,4] \times [0,1]$ are equidecomposable.

I know i can decompose $R_1$ into 4 sets of $[0,1) \times [0,1)$, leaving 4 boundary lines. Constructing the rectangle from this however, there is one edge "missing", as the square has 12 such boundary lines when decomposed into 4 pieces, while the rectangle has 13, and i am stuck here.
Where do i get this missing boundary, or in a more general sense which i assume is what i am missing, how do i show that an open set like $(0,1) \times (0,1)$ is equidecomposable to its closed counterpart $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ (since i assume it would be the same idea)?

Comment: I think one doesn't worry about boundary points when thinking about equidecomposability.

Comment: @GerryMyerson How exactly would not worrying concretely look then? Do i choose the decomposition with overlaps and ignore them, or is there something that implies why it would not be an issue from the start?

Comment: I usually think of equidecomposability as something you can do with a sheet of paper and a pair of scissors. Is a sheet of paper open, or is it closed? When you make a cut, do the new pieces of paper have boundary points where you've made the cut, or don't they? These are just questions that don't arise in the context of cutting paper.